# Property using the differentiation of an implicit function of three variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve the following exercise:
"Let $z=z(x,y)$ be defined in an implicit form by $z=x+yf(z)$, where $f$ is of class 2. Prove that, for any function of class one $\gamma(z)$, it is verified that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\gamma(z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}((\gamma(z)f(z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})$."
I have computed using the derivatives of an implicit function (taking $F(x,y)=x+yf(z)-z$) that $\frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial x}=-\frac{1}{yf'(z)-1}$ but I do not reach the equality asked to prove with this expression. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Could you please explain what "function of class 2" and "function of class 1" mean? Is this another name for [differentiability classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes) C² and C¹?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Maybe the terms I have used aren't so accurate or a bit more informal than those you have reffered. Sorry if that has caused confusion. But yeah, those are essentially differentiability classes.

Comment: I’m pretty sure there’s a mistake in the exercise. Does it check when $\gamma=1$?